# Returning value of private variable

Tags: java

My instructor said that if the class has private variables and when you want to return values of those variables via getters,  if their data types are primitive, you can just directly return their values, but if they're of reference types, a general rule of thumb is that you should almost always return Object.clone(). Then I'm wondering in what case you wouldn't need to return Object.clone()?

Comment: Don’t use Object.clone. It’s broken

Comment: I don't see any reason to bother casting any class to an object and back (ex: A Driver has many Cars ... why not return List<Car> directly?)

Comment: *" Then I'm wondering in what case you wouldn't need to return Object.clone()?"* What did your instructor say when you asked them?

Comment: He says so because you could change the object state by a reference to a private variable. However I think that using clone is not the correct solution. My own general rule is: if you need a getter for a private variable of a mutable reference type, you should check that your class interface is really the best solution for the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Your object (that you return) should control its own mutability.  You should be able to return a reference, and the object itself should be mutable or immutable depending on the object's definition and purpose.  If there are use cases where you can have immutable versions of otherwise mutable objects you should have a means of wrapping them in an immutable facade.  And BTW, your teacher is wrong, or has not kept up with Java best practices in the past 15 years.

Comment: Someone said if you are returning a copy of reference of immutable objecrs, by definition of immutability you can't mutate the state of object but can't you overwrite memory contents by the use of reference?

Answer (score 4):

> but if they're of reference types, a general rule of thumb is that you should almost always return Object.clone().

Usage of clone is discouraged. Probably you mean by creating a copy(*deep*) of the object and return.

> Then I'm wondering in what case you wouldn't need to return Object.clone()?

Whenever you want to allow the callers of your class to modify the data of your class.

Inshort, in case of mutable objects.

Answer (score 1):

If the members are immutable reference types such as `String`, `Integer`, etc... there is no need to create a copy of the instance variable in the getter method.

When an instance variable is mutable, returning the original value allows the caller of the getter method to mutate your object without calling a setter method. This is usually a bad practice, and can lead to hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> ...if they're of reference types, a general rule of thumb is that you should almost always return `Object.clone()`

You may want to make a copy, but not necessarily with `Object.clone`. This is typically called making a *defensive copy*.

Consider this class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Foo {
    private List<String> list;

    private String info;

    public Foo(String info) {
        this.list = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.info = info;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }
}
```

Neither `getList` nor `getInfo` makes a *copy* of the object it returns to the caller, they return a reference to the object. In the case of `getList`, that means code using the class can do this:

```
List<String> theList = foo.getList();
theList.add("Hi there");
```

...which changes the state of the list inside `foo`, without using any `foo` mutator method (`getList` isn't a mutating method).

In the case of `getInfo`, since strings are *immutable*, there's nothing the caller can do with the reference to the string that will change the state of `foo`.

> Then I'm wondering in what case you wouldn't need to return Object.clone()?

1. If what you're returning is immutable (like `String`), no need to make a defensive copy.
2. If you want users of the class to be able to change the state of `foo` without using a `foo` method, you don't want to make a defensive copy.

If what you're returning is mutable (like a `List`) and you *don't* want the caller to be able to change it, then:

1. Return an immutable version of it, perhaps via a wrapper (such as from [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-)).
2. Return a defensive copy of it.

Since copies can be expensive, you need to choose both `Foo`'s API and how you deal with the objects it contains with an eye toward memory use and performance **if** there's a good chance that those will be a factor in the use of the class.